# Neo4j Cypher return count and the actual data in the same query for pagination

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to avoid calling almost the same query twice - one time for count for pagination and then for the actual data, and combine them into the single Cypher call?

Comment: It is possible, but how performant that will be depends on the query

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show an example? This query for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425763/neo4j-cypher-query-does-many-db-hits I need to calculate also `count(childD)`

Comment: In the query present in the question, you are limiting multiple entities and ordering is also based on some custom logic `WITH childD, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes , criterionCoefficientSum  
ORDER BY  weight / criterionCoefficientSum DESC, childD.createdAt DESC`, in this case I believe we cannot fetch count and pagination data via a single query. I tried but couldn't figure out a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doing it in a single query was a requirement, you could do something along these lines, assuming you these parameters:

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "pageSize": 10
}
```

this query

```
MATCH (n:Movie) 
WITH COLLECT({title:n.title}) AS allResults
WITH allResults[($page * $pageSize)..($page+1)*$pageSize] AS pageResults,
     toInt(size(allResults)/$pageSize) + 1 AS numPages,
     size(allResults) AS totalCount
RETURN totalCount,$page, numPages, pageResults
```

returns

```
╒════════════╤═══════╤══════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"totalCount"│"$page"│"numPages"│"pageResults"                                                         │
╞════════════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│46          │0      │5         │[{"title":"Forrest Gump"},{"title":"Appolo 13"},{"title":"The Matrix"}│
│            │       │          │,{"title":"The Matrix Reloaded"},{"title":"The Matrix Revolutions"},{"│
│            │       │          │title":"The Devil's Advocate"},{"title":"A Few Good Men"},{"title":"To│
│            │       │          │p Gun"},{"title":"Jerry Maguire"},{"title":"Stand By Me"}]            │
└────────────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```